# Matrix with row and column indexed by $m$ subset

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request

Consider $\binom{n}{m}\times\binom{n}{m}$-matrix $M$ whose rows and columns are indexed by the subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with  $m$  elements. Suppose that $M_{A,B}$ only depends on $|A\cap B|$. Has such matrix being researched? In the $m=1$ case $M$ is the matrix with diagonal elements identical and non-diagonal elements identical respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The adjacency matrix of a [Johnson graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph) is such a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but in the interest of completeness it might be worth elaborating on Rebecca's answer. As Rebecca pointed out the adjacency matrix of a Johnson graph is one such matrix. Since the Johnson graphs are distance-regular it is possible to compute the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix explicitly. Moreover if one defines a basis $M^{(j)}_{A,B}$ to be 1 if $|A\cap B|=j$ and $0$ otherwise then one can compute the eigenvalues of an arbitrary linear combination of the matrices $M^{(j)}$. This is possible since the $M^{(j)}$ form a closed algebra called the Johnson scheme.

The eigenvalues are worked out in 
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jcd.21308

You could also look at Ito and Bannai's book on Algebraic Combinatorics, or Bailey's book on Association schemes.